How to populate the clipboard on a ubuntu system to insert data into an online excel?
I want to programatically populate an online excel sheet, i.e. I want to populate some rows with some columns of data. So instead of typing the data for 3 columns and 3 rows (that make 9 cells) as shown here:

which even includes a link, how can I "copy and paste" the data using "copy and paste", or the clipboard, or some other means?
I might have a python script that outputs the data I need to insert to that online excel, but instead of copying and pasting each cell individually, is it possible to do it with only one single "copy and paste" somehow?
Or at least how to insert 3 rows that are a link?
When I just copy and paste like the following
a   b   c

That only fills out one cell...
The idea is that you can easily copy a rectangular cells area with links etc and paste it at a different place in the sheet. So somehow some special information/data/characters are part of the clipboard, so excel "knows" which elements of the clipboard belong to what cell or link etc.

I think windows copy/paste command views tab delimited items as separate items and will use separate cells. I did test by creating a several data items separated by tabs in notepad, copied that and pasted into excel, resulting in seeing them in different cells.

I'm not sure this knowledge can be leveraged in program code to make the copy/paste to excel from an nonexcel source any more efficient.

Actually the tab thing seems to work and querying jira with a python script did help already save a lot of time. The links can be added with excel magic. Thanks!

@gns100, why not enlarge comment to an answer, since it helped Alex, and might help others as well? Thanks.
